# Twitter API using syntax with JSON

Tags: json, api

I am trying to find out the JSON http url to access the data but getting error, is the url call syntax error?

URL: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=5&screen_name=westor7&oauth_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&oauth_signature=ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET

Error message:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you have literally put `ACCESS_TOKEN` into your query? or is that just obscured values? Either way, you're using the wrong token and/or token/secret, and Twitter is properly rejecting your request.

Comment: You need to replace `ACCESS_TOKEN` and `ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET` with actual values. You get those by registering with Twitter for OAuth.

Comment: I had many problems while working with the twitter API. Keep in mind the order of the properties you sign. Also, the twitter api used to have a place where you could put your tokens and it'd show you what the signed strings and everything else should look like... good luck!

Comment: The ACCESS_TOKEN is the API KEY and the ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET is the API Secret but does not working...

Comment: The error is saying that whatever token and secret you're using aren't valid. Make sure you've copied them correctly, or get new ones.

Comment: What exacty is the correct url syntax-format to access the data?

Comment: @Cory i am using the ACCESS_TOKEN as API Key and ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET as API Secret and return me the 215 error code, does the url need any other auth parameters?

Comment: here's the twitter api console I was talking about before: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/tools/console

Comment: See https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline for the parameters.

Comment: The problem in the url is the auth part and not the other parameters, and your urls does not help, can you please give me the full login url syntax as an example?

Comment: I use this url on the browser: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=5&screen_name=westor7&oauth_consumer_key=API_KEY&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&oauth_signature=ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET

Comment: did anyone find something to help me please?

Comment: the twitter dev console shows you what twitter does with your credentials... how come that's no good for you?

Comment: Are you using the correct OAuth signature method?